# Will Godox TT350o work with Olympus EM10 M2?

Tags: olympus, godox

Will Godox TT350o work with Olympus EM10 M2?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the TT350-O is compatible with your camera body. [The Godox website](http://www.godox.com/EN/Products_Mini_Camera_Flash_TT350o.html) lists the following camera bodies on their compatibility list:

> Olympus: E-M10 II, E-M5 II, E-M1, E-PL8, E-PL7, E-PL6, E-PL5, E-P5, E-P3, PEN-F.
>
> Panasonic: DMC-GX85, DMC-G7, DMC-GF1, DMC-LX100, DMC-G85

In addition, the Flash Havoc blog has a comment from its author, elv, who states that this list of compatible bodies is merely what Godox has been able to test the flash against.  I own a Panasonic DMC-GX7, and my TT350-O works fine in all functions (HSS, TTL, MULTI, S1/S2, 2nd curtain, etc.) on the camera's hotshoe.

I also have no idea what you mean about the flash being "not that small". It's tiny for a speedlight with a tilt/swivel head! Godox gives the WxHxD in *millimeters* (140x62x38). That's 5.5"x2.4"x1.5"--i.e., about the same foot print as a 3x5 index card.  I find it to be the perfect size/weight for a mirrorless body.

Comment: I don't suppose you have any experience with Godox flashes in terms of its quality / reliability?

Comment: @Calyth my gear is very new, so no, but my feel would be it's on a par with Yongnuo gear.